# Passing a stream from silverlight to browser

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, silverlight-4.0

I have a silverlight application that retrieves a file from Amazon s3. At this point I am using a SaveFileDialog to save it to disk.

I am looking for a better way of saving the file.I have looked into and implemented Isolated storage but ultimately decided to not use it because of all the restrictions.

Also, silverlight restricts saving a file outside isolated storage without the save file dialog, so I cannot save a file and then pass the file path to the browser. so this is not possible

```
 HtmlPage.Window.Navigate(urlToFile, "_blank");
```

What are the options I have left now to pass this stream to a browser?

Comment: For what do you want to store it? Should it be available to the user afterwards? If it should be available to the user e.g. in his download folder than you can try to just show some link in your app. Clicking on it would bring up the normal browser download dialog.

Comment: The file is stored in Amazon S3. The AWS SDK for .NET does not work with silverlight. Also I need to authenticate the request so I cannot put a hyperlink to the file. Due to security restrictions for silverlight  Cannot save directly to the download folder, so I have to show the save file dialog(which I want to bypass). So the only option I am left with is to get the file in silverlight app as a stream from Amazon and somehow pass it to a webpage. Also, its not important that it should be available to user afterwords as long as he can view it in the browser

Comment: And what is that file? Something you will show inside of silverlight (like a movie or audio or image) or something where the user requires some external software like MS Word or Photoshop or something? In first case you simply can use something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1789846/silverlight-load-image-with-filestream but for the second case he has to store it locally and open it (= file save dialog) or you have to write some webserver (e.g. asp.net) code which gets the file from amazon and let the user download it unauthorized or using iis/asp.net authentication.

Comment: Unfortunately it's the second type. The files are mostly pdf docs but can also be word or excel documents. I do have a saveFileDialog and it works perfectly, the only thing is I wanted to bypass it. I am coming to a conclusion that what I want is not possible. So I have implemented what seems to be close to your suggestion. Create a pre-signed URL and pass it to browser. Works fine now

Comment: ok :) nice it works now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a feature in silverlight 4 where you can run it [out of the browser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  In this mode you have [elevated permissions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd550721%28v=vs.95%29.aspx#special_features_for_outofbrowser_applications).  The one that would be of most interest to you is

> File system access. Trusted applications can access System.IO types
>   and related types that are otherwise unavailable to Silverlight. These
>   APIs provide direct read and write access to files in user folders on
>   the local computer. For more information, see How to: Access the Local
>   File System in Trusted Applications.

Outside of this, there is no other way to save a file to the users desktop without using the `SaveFileDialog`

Comment: That is the conclusion I reached. I cant run my application out of browser so that option is off the table. I have found a work around and as mentioned in my comments under the question.